# What would be the best way to require modules only once for several files?

Tags: node.js

I have a code where several files depend on the same module and the main file `app.js` needs these files.

`./lib/utils.js` need the modules: `node-fetch`, `querystring`

`./lib/funcs.js` need the modules: `node-fetch`, `cheerio`, `lodash` and `./lib/utils.js`

And finally the `app.js` needs the files above `./lib/utils.js` and `./lib/funcs.js`.

What would be the best way to simplify several requires in all of these files?

Preventing this from happening:

> utils.js

`const fetch = require("node-fetch")`

> funcs.js

`const fetch = require("node-fetch")`

Comment: There is no need to prevent multiple require as node.js caches the request and uses the cached one on consecutive calls

Comment: @ISAE, the purpose would be the code's eligibility, that is, to avoid the same line in several files

Comment: Don’t do this. Each file should reference the modules it needs.